# What is an alternative to RouteFactoryAttribute in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to implement API-versioning (APIs passed as a query) using constraints. Previously, I could use `RouteFactoryAttribute` and `IHttpRouteConstraint`. Now, there is `IRouteConstraint` for routing constraint; however, I don't find any alternatives to `RouteFactoryAttribute` that I can use.

Answer (score 1):

add AddApiVersioning extension method to IServiceCollection to set up api versioning.

namespace: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning